# About autoindent and postbreak in the package listings

Tags: listings, line-breaking, indentation, comments

I am using the package `listings` to show my Matlab code. The code was pre-typed in a file and everything will be loaded from the file and a `.tex` file will be generated automatically to show the code with `lstlisting`. Now, I am worrying about the long line and I need it break line automatically so I add the `breaklines` options. It works but if the breaking point is on the comment string, the line break will break the comment into two parts which look pretty ugly because in Matlab the comment must start with `%` symbol and now the second line is shown in comment style but not prefixed with `%`. I read the `listings` package documentation and it mention the `postbreak` and `autoindent` options. I don't understand how it work, I try the example shown in the document but didn't get the same results as shown there. Anyway, my question is if it is possible for `listings` package or other package to break the comment in a smart way such that the broken line will be aligned and correct prefix with be added to the broken comment. For example, a long command is shown as

```
delta = 0.001;    % interval of the time slice between two different signals measured in different point
```

In the following environment,

```
\begin{lstlisting}[postbreak=\space, breakautoindent=true, breakindent=10pt, breaklines]
  delta = 0.001;    % interval of the time slice between two different signals measured in different point
\end{lstlisting}
```

It shows

```
  delta = 0.001;    % interval of the time slice between two 
    different signals measured in different point
```

But I want it to be

```
  delta = 0.001;    % interval of the time slice between two 
                    % different signals measured in different point
```

Comment: Sounds tricky, but would be cool.

Comment: Use `listings` line-numbering functionality. No matter where line breaks occur, your readers will then be able to easily determine whether a given line break was present in the source code or was introduced by `listings`. Also, consider using the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a feature request for `listings`.

Answer (score 6):

The `listings` package doesn't offer the possibility to align broken lines with an arbitrary part of the output, so some hand adjustment is needed. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[postbreak=\%\space, 
  breakautoindent=true, breakindent=108pt, breaklines]
  delta = 0.001;    % interval of the time slice between two different signals measured in different point
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

seems to print the desired output, but does rely on the fact that the comments all start in the same column. I suspect going beyond that is a non-trivial feature request.